# For which integers n can the set{1,2,.., n}be partitioned into two subsets A&B such that the sum of squares of each is equal

Tags: number-theory

For which integers n can the set $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ be partitioned into two subsets $A$ and $B$ such that the sum of squares of the elements of $A$ is equal to the sum of squares of the elements in $B$?

for example, it works for n=7

```
A={3,5,6}    ,  sum of squares = 70
B={1,2,4,7}  ,  sum of squares = 70
```

A great resourse:

> https://www.reddit.com/r/mathriddles/comments/30alm8/xy_movie_problems/#sp

but it is incomplete

Comment: You posted yourself the answer of your own question: so what is your question ("I don't understand that answer" is too vague)?

Comment: i asked a question and linked a resource to help you help me get an answer, the answers given on the link are incomplete

Comment: Are you also demanding that the sum of the elements in A equal the sum of elements in B?  You don't say that, but it seems so from your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All $n \ge 7, n \equiv 0,3 \pmod{4}$ satisfy the condition.

Denote $S(X)$ as the sum of the elements of set $X$.

> **Lemma.** We can partition the set $X= \{ 1,3,5, \cdots , 2n+1 \}$ with $n \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ into two subsets $A,B$ so that $S(A)=S(B)$.

*Proof.* If $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ then there are $\tfrac{n+1}{2}$ pairs $(i,2n+1-i)$ so we can pick arbitrary $\tfrac{n+1}{4}$ pairs to put in $A$ and the rest put in $B$. If $n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ then there are $\tfrac{n-7}{2}$ pairs $(i,2n+2-i)$ and we exclude the pairs $(1,2n+1), (n, n+2)$. Pick $\tfrac{n-9}{4}$ such pairs to put in $A$ and the rest $\tfrac{n-5}{4}$ pairs to put in $B$. At this point, we will have $S(B)-S(A)= 2n+2$. Put $2n+1,n+2$ in $A$ and $1, n$ in $B$. Now we obtain $S(A)=S(B)$.  $\square$

Now, back to our problem. We must have $2 \mid \sum_{i=1}^n i^2= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ or $n \equiv 0,3 \pmod{4}$. We will prove that all $n \ge 7, n \equiv 0,3 \pmod{4}$ satisfy the condition.

Indeed, if $n \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ then note that $\{ (n+1-i)-i \; | \; 1 \le i \le n/2 \}= \{ 1,3,5, \cdots , n-1 \}$ where $n-1 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. Hence, by applying the lemma, we can partition $S$ into subsets $A,B$ so that if $i \in A$ then $n+1-i \in B$ and $S(A)=S(B)$. From this, we follow $(n+1)(S(A)-S(B))=0$ or $S(A^2)-S(B^2)=0$ where $S(X^2)$ is sum of squares of elements in $X$.

For $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ then $\{ (n-i)-i | 0 \le i \le (n-1)/2 \}= \{ 1,3, \cdots , n \}$. Hence, from the lemma, we deduce that $S$ can be partitioned into subsets $A,B$ so that if $i \in A$ then $n-i \in B$ for $1 \le i \le (n-1)/2$ and $S(A)=S(B)$. We follow $n(S(A)-S(B))=0$ or $S(A^2)=S(B^2)$.

We are done.